# Cannot convert Error on updating a attribute in ad using set-aduser

Tags: powershell, csv

I am getting an error when tyring to run this script.  I am running the -whatif and get this error:

I get these errors

```
TerminatingError(Set-ADUser): "Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'EmployeeID'. Specified method is not supported."
```

The csv file looks like this

```
employeeID,name
78549625,ktest
43939399,dtest
```

Here is the script:

```
$stuff = Import-Csv c:\temp\empid\finalexport_test.csv
$empid = $stuff.employeeid
$userid = $stuff.name
$empid
$userid


foreach ($user in $userid)
{
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user -EmployeeID $empid -whatif

    $empid
    $user

Write "The user $user is now assigned the employee Id of $empid.  This was not actually written to AD yet"
write "The information below shows the user and the feild that would have been updated."
Get-ADUser -identity $user -Property * | select samaccountname, employeeid
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are using the For-each loop wrong.

You do a foreach on the userid because there are multiple values in there, and just like userid empid also has multiple values (is an array)
So i would suggest changing the script to this:

(also you missed a bracket at the end of the foreach loop)

```
$stuff = Import-Csv c:\temp\empid\finalexport_test.csv

foreach ($user in $stuff)
{
    $empid = $user.employeeID
    $userid = $user.name
    Set-ADUser -Identity $userid -EmployeeID $empid -whatif

    $empid
    $user

    Write "The user $userid is now assigned the employee Id of $empid.  This was not actually written to AD yet"
    write "The information below shows the user and the feild that would have been updated."
}
Get-ADUser -identity $user -Property * | select samaccountname, employeeid
```

Comment: Kage, thank you for the quick and accurate answer.  Your the man!